# Getting a date from a 4 digit strange date format in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-function, to-date, sql-date-functions

I receive a string from decoding codebar-128, once I parse all data in the code readed I get a date in a strange 4 digits format: 'YDDD'

The 'Y' digit represents the last digit of the Year (0-9).  The 'DDD' digits represent the Day of year (1-366).

The issue is the ambiguous value of the Year.  The rule to solve that issue must be the follow:

1. The Year computed for 'Y' digit must be the nearest year to Sysdate year.
2. Never the difference from Sysdate year and computed year for the 'Y' digit will be greater than 4.

My code:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, TO_DATE('0213', 'YDDD'), TO_DATE('1212', 'YDDD'), 
        TO_DATE('2212', 'YDDD'), TO_DATE('3212', 'YDDD'), TO_DATE('4213', 'YDDD'),
        TO_DATE('6212', 'YDDD'), TO_DATE('7212', 'YDDD'), TO_DATE('8213', 'YDDD'),
        TO_DATE('9212', 'YDDD')
FROM dual;
```

**This is that I need to get:**

```
+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|  SYSDATE  | TO_DATE('20213','YYDDD') | TO_DATE('21212','YYDDD') | TO_DATE('22212','YYDDD') | TO_DATE('23212','YYDDD') | TO_DATE('24213','YYDDD') | TO_DATE('16213','YYDDD') | TO_DATE('17212','YYDDD') | TO_DATE('18212','YYDDD') | TO_DATE('19212','YYDDD') |
+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| 26-JUN-20 | 31-JUL-20                | 31-JUL-21                | 31-JUL-22                | 31-JUL-23                | 31-JUL-24                | 31-JUL-16                | 31-JUL-17                | 31-JUL-18                | 31-JUL-19                |
+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

*As you can see, if I had the penultimate digit of the year there would be no issue.*

**This is that I'm really getting:**

```
+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|  SYSDATE  | TO_DATE('0213','YDDD') | TO_DATE('1212','YDDD') | TO_DATE('2212','YDDD') | TO_DATE('3212','YDDD') | TO_DATE('4213','YDDD') | TO_DATE('6212','YDDD') | TO_DATE('7212','YDDD') | TO_DATE('8213','YDDD') | TO_DATE('9212','YDDD') |
+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 26-JUN-20 | 31-JUL-20              | 31-JUL-21              | 31-JUL-22              | 31-JUL-23              | 31-JUL-24              | 31-JUL-26              | 31-JUL-27              | 31-JUL-28              | 31-JUL-29              |
+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: If your rules (1) and (2) apply, why does '1' becomes 2001 instead of 2021? That isn't closer to, and is more than 4 years away from, today? I'm not sure if that's just an issue with how you've generated that. It might be helpful to show your expected output by copying what you actually get and making the necessary changes, possibly explaining each one?

Comment: @AlexPoole you're all right!  '1' must be '2021'.  I've fixed it.

Comment: Needless to mention that you should change your design to proper `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) data type as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it up in multiple with clauses so it is easier to understand, you can join it into a single query if you want.

```
WITH sampledata (dt) AS
(
 SELECT '0213' FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '1212' FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '2212' FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '3212' FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '4213' FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '5213' FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '6212' FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '7212' FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '8213' FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '9212' FROM DUAL 
), parsed_sampledata (yr, ddd) AS
(
SELECT substr(d.dt,1, 1) + TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY') as yr, substr(d.dt,2,3) as ddd
  FROM sampledata d
)
SELECT TO_DATE(ddd||yr - (CASE WHEN yr - TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY') < 5 THEN 0 ELSE 10 END),'DDDYY')  
  FROM parsed_sampledata d;

31-JUL-2020
31-JUL-2021
31-JUL-2022
31-JUL-2023
31-JUL-2024
01-AUG-2015
30-JUL-2016
31-JUL-2017
01-AUG-2018
31-JUL-2019
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the single-digit value with the last digit of the current year, and if the difference is more than 4, adjust but 10 years. But it needs to go both ways; once 'today' is in 2026, you'll be adding 10 years instead.

```
select column_value as val,
  to_date(column_value, 'YDDD') as dt1,
  to_number(substr(column_value, 1, 1)) as y,
  mod(extract(year from sysdate), 10) as yy,
  case
    when to_number(substr(column_value, 1, 1)) - mod(extract(year from sysdate), 10) > 4 then -10
    when mod(extract(year from sysdate), 10) - to_number(substr(column_value, 1, 1)) > 4 then 10
    else 0
  end as adj,
  to_date(column_value, 'YDDD')
    + case
        when to_number(substr(column_value, 1, 1)) - mod(extract(year from sysdate), 10) > 4 then -10
        when mod(extract(year from sysdate), 10) - to_number(substr(column_value, 1, 1)) > 4 then 10
        else 0
      end * interval '1' year as dt2,
  add_months(to_date(column_value, 'YDDD'),
    12 * case
        when to_number(substr(column_value, 1, 1)) - mod(extract(year from sysdate), 10) > 4 then -10
        when mod(extract(year from sysdate), 10) - to_number(substr(column_value, 1, 1)) > 4 then 10
        else 0
      end) as dt2
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('0213', '1212', '2212', '3212', '4213',
                                '5212', '6212', '7212', '8213', '9212'));
```

which gets

```
VAL  DT1                 Y         YY        ADJ DT2        DT2       
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
0213 2020-07-31          0          0          0 2020-07-31 2020-07-31
1212 2021-07-31          1          0          0 2021-07-31 2021-07-31
2212 2022-07-31          2          0          0 2022-07-31 2022-07-31
3212 2023-07-31          3          0          0 2023-07-31 2023-07-31
4213 2024-07-31          4          0          0 2024-07-31 2024-07-31
5212 2025-07-31          5          0        -10 2015-07-31 2015-07-31
6212 2026-07-31          6          0        -10 2016-07-31 2016-07-31
7212 2027-07-31          7          0        -10 2017-07-31 2017-07-31
8213 2028-07-31          8          0        -10 2018-07-31 2018-07-31
9212 2029-07-31          9          0        -10 2019-07-31 2019-07-31
```

I haven't verified the future-year behaviour so you probably need to test and adjust that as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you some ideas:

```
WITH DATES_LIST AS
(
 SELECT '0213' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '1212' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '2212' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '3212' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '4213' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '5213' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '6213' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '7212' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '8212' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
 SELECT '9212' AS D FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT  TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(D,'^\d{1}',
        CASE WHEN BOTT_R <= UPP_R THEN BOT ELSE UPP END),'YYDDD') AS YEAR 
        FROM (
select D,(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'RR') - 10) + regexp_substr(D, '^\d{1}') BOT,
       ABS((TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'RR') - 10) + regexp_substr(D, '^\d{1}')-TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'RR')) BOTT_R,
       TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'RR') + regexp_substr(D, '^\d{1}') UPP,
       (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'RR') + regexp_substr(D, '^\d{1}')) - TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'RR') UPP_R
        from DATES_LIST);
```

If you need to convert to many variables(many) my advise is to create a DETERMINISTIC function.

Regards.

Comment: I'm not sure this is following the rules; it still gives 2001 for your example, not 2021? Converting the 1 to 01  doesn't seem to add much (and could be done with simple string concatenation), but not sure that matters in the bigger picture.

Comment: My apologies, please check once again, I did omit part of the logic in my previous example.